# Why does Nhibernate.Linq throws me exception "The method Compareto is not implemented"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

I've been struggling a long time with this problem and I can't get it to work properly. What I want to do, is to get entries with a date earlier than a specified entry. For you to understand, I'll to show you this code snippet:

```
        var post = _session.Linq<PostModel>()
            .Where(o => o.PostId == id)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return _session.Linq<PostModel>()
            .Where(o => DateTime.Compare(post.PostDate, o.PostDate) >= 0)
            .ToList();
```

This doesn't work! It will throw me an exception saying:

```
The method Compareto is not implemented.
```

I've tried implementing "IComparer" to my PostModel, but that seems not be the problem here. Although, this will work if I first convert all the entries to a list, then compare them, like this:

```
        return _session.Linq<PostModel>().ToList()
            .Where(o => DateTime.Compare(post.PostDate, o.PostDate) >= 0)
            .ToList()
```

But to my understanding, converting all entries to a list before any cases, will cause NHibernate selecting all entries. This might not be a problem if we're talking about a small amount of entries, but in the long term, this will waste some time.

Does anyone have any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the NHibernate linq provider needs to convert the call to `DateTime.Compare` into SQL so it can be executed on the server. As the error states, this has not been implemented, although you may be able to change your query to:

```
_session.Linq<PostModel>()
            .Where(o => post.PostDate >= o.PostDate)
            .ToList();
```

which probably will be implemented.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that before.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but it may not be liking the static call in your where cause. Perhaps just try using the built in relational operators on datetime like this:

```
.Where(o => o.PostDate >= post.PostDate)
```

I think about trying to convert your version to SQL and I can't see how they would know to do it, even with all of the black magic NHibernate does.

Answer (score 2):

Lee has it bang-on. The NHibernate LINQ provider has no way of converting the method call into SQL, which is why a NotImplementedException is being thrown. You can provide NHibernate with a way to translate this call into SQL via NHibernate's LINQ provider extension model:

http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html

Comment: Very smart implementation, I'll take a look at that. Thanks for the link!